# Raycast without using a collider

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, raycasting, voxel

I am doing a Voxel game and my engine was using Physics.raycasts and Mesh colliders for getting the coordinates of the block you clicked on until now. I decided to remove the mesh collider, because it was just eating too much performance in some situations and I got fps dropdowns to 0.1fps for a few seconds (eg you should be able to scroll through the y-layers) and I only needed it for raycasting. I don't use any other physics related stuff. Without the mesh colliders the framerate is stable at 60 to 100 fps, but now I find it hard finding another way getting the information on which block I am clicking.

Any suggestions?

So far I was using this piece of code:

```
public Vector3? GetBlockCursor(){
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;

    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
        hit.point += (hit.normal * -0.5f);
        hit.point = new Vector3(Mathf.RoundToInt(hit.point.x), Mathf.RoundToInt(hit.point.y),
                                Mathf.RoundToInt(hit.point.z));
        return hit.point;
    }
    else return null;
}
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qdwUkYrHosk This guy made aspects of minecraft in unity. He says he had good performance with box colliders. Although I don't know if box colliders would suit your needs as a voxel engine doesn't necessarily mean perfect squares.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to check that video out now! I was just switching to Box Colliders right after posting, which was a significant performance boost!

Comment: Unfortunately its a bit fast and I am not creating a Minecraft Game, but rather have a Gnomoria or Towns engine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say as it always depends on the game logic what and where optimisations are efficient. Basically one or a few ray cast(s) per frame should not be a big deal for PhysX, so I think there are other culprits. Some Suggestions (maybe you have considererd them already):

- Use compound colliders especially box and sphere s. [Rigidbody manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html)
- Always attach rigidbodies to moving items
- Limit the calls to `GetBlockCursor` to once per Update or even less by calling it every 2nd or 3rd Update only
- If you need more than one raycast consider using [Physics.RaycastAll](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.RaycastAll.html)
- If the physics engine is to blame for significant frame rate Drops, check whether you can use *layers* to optimise calculations
- Use the profiler (provided you have Pro license)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! After spending some time rearranging the GetBlockCursor() function it works now fine with Box Colliders, which are very much faster than Mesh Colliders. The problem was and is not the raycasting, but it was the recalculation of the Mesh Collider I was doing, which just needed too much time. I have an accurate selection now even without the Mesh Collider, but using some math instead.